# Preventing a disabled user logging in using Rails and Devise

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, devise

In my rails 3.2.11 app, I am using devise to handle user login. All works great, but I want to add new validations to the login, so that if a disabled flag is set to true, it prevents that user from logging in, until an administrator re-enables them.

It looks like I can override the devise sessionscontroller, and handle the functionality there, but going through the devise documents, I noticed the validatable option, which looks like it should be able to handle what I am trying to do (and be a cleaner solution).

So my questions are:

1) Is my understanding of the validatable option correct, that it can be used to add more login validations?

2) And if yes, how would I be able to use it to check the disabled flag i have in my user model?

Regards,

Answer (score 0):

The Validatable option isn't what you think it is. It just does all the necessary basic validations for email and password. From: http://www.rubydoc.info/github/plataformatec/devise/Devise/Models/Validatable

> Validatable creates all needed validations for a user email and
>   password. It's optional, given you may want to create the validations
>   by yourself. Automatically validate if the email is present, unique
>   and its format is valid. Also tests presence of password, confirmation
>   and length.

Doing it your own way overriding the `SessionsController` might be your best bet. In your case, what I would probably do is add an `after_filter :check_user_flag` to check that flag, and if disabled then sign the user out with a message explaining why.